# How to change the location of classes generated by MapStruct?

Tags: java, gradle, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct to generate the mapping between the JAXB classes and my domain classes. 
I am using gradle plugin as described in MapStruct official site. During the compilation process, the classes are generated in "build/generated/sources/apt/main".
How can i change this location? I am not able to find any guide for gradle though there is a compiler flag to change it through ant script, but unfortunately it is not working for gradle
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not linked to MapStruct, but to the way the gradle apt plugin works and how it tells the Java compiler to place the generated sources.

To configure the generated sources of the plugin according to the configuration [documentation](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin#configuration). One needs to extend the `aptOptions` of the compile. The property controlling the destination of the generated is `generatedSourcesDestinationDir`